# Javascript selecting right element

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Here is my html:

```
<div id="TAB_CLIENTPANE" class="panel_tabs k-widget k-header k-tabstrip" style="height: 328px;" data-role="tabstrip" tabindex="0" role="tablist" aria-activedescendant="TAB_CLIENTPANE_ts_active">
    <ul class="k-tabstrip-items k-reset">
        <li class="k-item k-state-default k-tab-on-top k-state-active k-first" role="tab" aria-controls="TAB_CLIENTPANE-1" aria-selected="true">
            <span class="k-link">Summary Report</span>
            <a class="tab_win k-button"><span class="k-icon k-i-maximize"></span></a>
            <a class="tab_close k-button"><span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="k-item k-state-default k-last" role="tab" aria-controls="TAB_CLIENTPANE-2">
            <span class="k-link">Profit Report</span>
            <a class="tab_win k-button"><span class="k-icon k-i-maximize"></span></a>
            <a class="tab_close k-button"><span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="k-content k-state-active" style="display: block; height: 290px;" aria-expanded="true" role="tabpanel" id="TAB_CLIENTPANE-1">
        <div id="POSITIONREPORT" data-role="grid" class="k-grid k-widget k-secondary" style="height: 288px;">
            <!--lots of divs etc-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="k-content" style="display: none; height: 290px;" aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="false" role="tabpanel" id="TAB_CLIENTPANE-2">
        <div id="PROFITREPORT" data-role="grid" class="k-grid k-widget k-secondary" style="height: 288px;">
            <!--lots of divs etc-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to write a method that works as explained in the following description:

```
function get_li(id_of_div){
    // the parameter id_of_div will be the id of divs, 
    // eg: "POSTIONREPORT", "PROFITREPORT" etc.
    // let's say the parameter passed to the function is "PROFITREPORT"
    // PROFITREPORT is the second div after the ul element, so
    // the function has to return the second li element of the ul
}
```

How do I have to select the right li?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you edit the HTML ? I mean can you assign some `ID` or extra classes to your `LI` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return you the right `li`:

```
function get_li(id_of_div){
    var index = $('#TAB_CLIENTPANE > div').index($('#' + id_of_div).parent());
    return $('#TAB_CLIENTPANE > ul > li').eq(index);
}
```

JSFiddle Example - http://jsfiddle.net/zBkyJ/

Answer (score 0):

```
return $('li').eq($('.k-content').index($('#'+id_of_div).parent()));
```

---

That should get you the required element

Comment: But this piece of code is just a part of the whole html. How can I make sure that those are in the parent of PROFITREPORT? I'm referring to the TAB_CLIENTPANE.